# how to extract values from multiple XMLs into excel?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have a large number of XMLs all loosely of this form (some have a different number of fields but all contain certain information that I want)

```
<message>
  <stdHeader> don't want </stdheader>
  <formdata>
     <field1>
        <subfield1>
            <type> don’t want </type>
            <name> want </name>
        </subfield1>
        <subfield2> want </subfield2>
        <subfield3> don't want </subfield4>
    </field1>
    <field2> don't want  </field2>
    <field3>
        <subfield1>
            <givenName> want  </givenName>
            <familyName> want  </familyName>
    </field3>
 </formdata>
 <aaaa>don't want </aaaa>  
 <bbbb>don't want</bbbb>  
 <cccc>don't want</cccc>  
 <dddd>don't want</dddd>  
 <eeee>don't want</eeee>  
 <ffff>don't want</ffff>  
</message>
```

I want a table in excel with column headings 'name','subfield3', 'givenName', 'familyName' (from above) with each row having the values of these from each of the XMLs. I am a beginner with programming so I don't know  how to 1. extract only those values I want from a single xml and 2.write some code to do 1. for every XML file in the folder. Can anyone help me out?

edit:

sample actual xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <message submitted="y" xmlns="u">
 <s><m>4</m><me>0</me>
 <oc>I</oc>
 <os>E</os><dr>21</dr>
 <tr>1</tr><dc>20/dc>
 <tc>1</tc><ds>2</ds>
 <ts>1</ts></sh><formData><c><identifier edgeitem="ZCO01b">
 <type edgeitem="ZCO01b">C</type><value edgeitem="ZCO01b">172</value>
 </identifier><name edgeitem="ZCO01a">JMTGN</name></c>
 <pb><ch><of><ef edgeitem="ZRP04b">20</ef><ad edgeitem="ZRG03c">
 <adL edgeitem="ZRP04d">2MR1</adL>
 <co edgeitem="ZRP04d">A</co><ov>true</ov>
 </ad></of></ch></pb><of><ch edgeitem="ZSD06a">
 <of><pe><ne edgeitem="ZSD06c"><gi edgeitem="ZSD06c">k</gi>
 <fa edgeitem="ZSD06c">o</fa>
 </ne><bi edgeitem="ZSD06d"><da edgeitem="ZSD06d">196</da>
 <ci edgeitem="ZSD06d">MNE</ci><st edgeitem="ZSD06d">VC</st>
 <co edgeitem="ZSD06d">Aua</co></bi>
 </pe><ad edgeitem="ZSD06h"><ad edgeitem="ZSD06h">24IC86</adL><co edgeitem="ZSD06h">uia</co><ov edgeitem="ZSD06i">true</ov><not><daC edgeitem="ZSD06b">29</daC>
 </not></ad></of><of><pe><name edgeitem="ZSD06c"><gs edgeitem="ZSD06c">jane</gs>
 <fae edgeitem="ZSD06c">ci</fae></name><bi edgeitem="ZSD06d"><da edgeitem="ZSD06d">198</da><ci edgeitem="ZSD06d">MLB</ci><st edgeitem="ZSD06d">VC</st>
 <co edgeitem="ZSD06d">Aul</co></bi></pe><ad edgeitem="ZSD06h"><adL edgeitem="ZSD06h">24IC</adL><co edgeitem="ZSD06h">uia</co><ov edgeitem="ZSD06i">true</ov>
 <not><daC edgeitem="ZSD06b">209</daC>
 </not></ad></of></ch></of><si><name edgeitem="ZDC00a"><givenNames edgeitem="ZDC00a">John </givenNames>
 <familyName edgeitem="ZDC00a">Citizen</familyName></name><ca edgeitem="ZDC00b">DI</ca><daS edgeitem="ZDC00c">200</daS><dec edgeitem="ZDC00d">true</dec></si></formData>
 <mes><asi><ebu><re>746</re>
 </ebu><asc><doc>181</doc></asc></asi>
 <cus><edg><re><type>RE</type>
 <qu>42</qu></re><ac>A08</ac>
 <tra>60</tra>
 <seq>1</se><tr>7046</tr>
 <mailbox>PR</mailbox><mode>PROCESS</mode></edge></customer></messageIdentifier>
 <asc><lo><ag>442</ag></loy></asc>
 <asco><re><dod>
 <dete>true</dete><fe>
 <lod>258</lod><lod>213</lod>
 <tot>0.00</tot></fe></dod></re>
 <prs><m>PRS</m><wa>false</wa><deb>false</deb>
 <maid>DP2</maid>
 <re>false</re></pro></asco>
 <wo><aga><ag>2</ag><agn>ATD</agn><co>LNY</co><pos>
 <adL>PO60</adL><adL>C3145</adL><co>AUA</co><asd>15055</asd>
 </pos><pe><te><nr>077</nr>
 </te></ph><fx><te><nr>057</nr>
 </te></fx></aga></wa></message>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sub iterates through all files in a folder and if it finds any XMLs, it calls the second sub

---

```vb
Option Explicit

'in code editor: Tools > References > checkbox in Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Public Sub ProcessXMLs()
    Const FOLDER_NAME   As String = "C:\Tmp"        '<- update this path

    Dim tags As Variant, hdrs As Variant, rowID As Long
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, f As File

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    hdrs = Array("FileName", "ItemID", "Name", "GivenName", "FamilyName")
    tags = Array("FileName", "value", "name", "givenNames", "familyName")

    With Sheet1
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(tags) + 1)).Value2 = hdrs
        rowID = 2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each f In fso.GetFolder(FOLDER_NAME).Files   'iterate through files
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xml" Then
                .Cells(rowID, 1).Value2 = fso.GetBaseName(f) & ".xml"
                ReadTags Sheet1, fso.OpenTextFile(f.Path, ForReading), rowID, tags
                rowID = rowID + 1
            End If
        Next
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---

This sub extracts values in the 4 tags, one file at the time:

```vb
Private Sub ReadTags(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal fsoFile As TextStream, _
                     ByVal rowID As Long, ByVal tags As Variant)

    Dim ln As String, val As String, i As Long, s1 As Long, s2 As Long

    With fsoFile
        Do While Not .AtEndOfStream       'file stream is open

            ln = Trim(.ReadLine)          'read each line

            If Len(ln) > 0 Then           'if text line is not empty extract tags
                For i = 1 To UBound(tags) 'find each tag - start and closing
                    s1 = InStr(1, ln, "<" & tags(i), 0)
                    s2 = InStr(s1 + 1, ln, "</" & tags(i) & ">", 0)
                    If s1 > 0 And s2 > 0 Then
                        s1 = InStr(s1, ln, """>", 0) + 2
                        ws.Cells(rowID, i + 1).Value2 = Trim(Mid(ln, s1, s2 - s1))
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: where in the code is this searching for the file? I replaced "C:\Tmp\file.xml"  with where my XMLs are located but it only prints this location in A2 and the fields B2-E2 are empty.

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how you can search all files in a folder

Comment: Hi Paul, this successfully cycles through all the files in the folder but it is still only printing the file names in col A and while cols B and E have the correct headings, B2:E4 remain empty. Do you know what the problem could be? I've edited the original post to include an example of an actual xml file where the values I want would be "172","JMTNGN", "john" and "doe".

Comment: Including of an actual xml helps quite a bit - I know what the problem is and I'm working on it. quick question: is the edgeitem code the same for the corresponding field (ex. `<value edgeitem="ZCO01b">`, `<name edgeitem="ZCO01a">`, `<givenNames edgeitem="ZDC00a">`, `<familyName edgeitem="ZDC00a">`) in all files? - I need to know if I can rely on the same string to identify each field in all files

Comment: some files in the folder have no 'edge item' and instead have just <value> ... </value> and <givenNames>...</givenNames>. However for the ones that do have edge item within the tag the Z... code is the same so for all files with edge item within the tag it will always be <value edgeitem = "ZCO01">..</value> and <givenNames edgeitem ="ZDC00a"> </givenNames> and so on for the other two fields.

Comment: I just made another update that ignores the codes; there might still be issues for the ones without the "edge". I'll remove the "edge" from my latest update and it should work for all xmls

Comment: still does the same thing I'm afraid, column A gets filled with the file names but cols B-E are empty apart from the headers.

Comment: I tested it again and it works; can you copy your actual XML example and save it exactly the way it is in a new file. If that works, the tags might be slightly different in your other files. For example you have a tag "<givenName**s**" in the actual XML, but it is "<givenName" in the initial example - this causes an issue. Make sure that the tags I have in the first sub (ProcessXMLs) exist in your files: `"<value"`, `"<name"`, `"<givenNames"`, `"<familyName"`

Comment: It worked with the exact example I added to the OP but not with the XMLs I had. However, I opened one of the actual XMLs in my browser  and copy-pasted everything there to notepad and saved that as an XML, then tested it and it worked perfectly. Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to open one if the XMLs directly in Notepad, without opening it in the browser first. If you can see normal text in Notepad replace your sample in the OP with that text (obfuscate any sensitive info) and we can look at the tags inside; I can also fix the code if it's needed, but I think the issue is caused by the tags

Comment: I replaced the sample with the text from copying the xml into notepad. (I added the spaces)

Comment: Your actual XML file has custom and nested tags and it made it it more difficult to extract the values so I made some important changes, but if all your files fallow the same standard this update should work. Try it again and please let me know if it works